# WCF REST Caching - Client Side & Server Side

Tags: wcf, rest

I have wirtten a RESTful WCF Service.  Incorporating E-Tags, expires headers.

The caching works great when using it from a browser.  However how does the caching work when calling it from a WCF Channel Factory or .NET Web Request Objects?

So in the scenario where I have my website calling the WCF restful service when a 304 not modified response is returned to me.  How do I handle this.  The browser detects this fine and returns the unmodified version from its cache.

However when the client is not the browser do I need to write my own version of the cache similiar to the way the browser caches?

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're going to have to handle that yourself, same as that you're responsbile for sending the datetime in the request, so the server can determine if there was a change. I would look at the [RSS Bandit source](http://www.rssbandit.org/) for a sample implementation.

Answer (score 2):

We have a sample that illustrates how to do this  (using .NET 4) http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/cannonicalRESTEntity